# Beginner question on mySQL and PHP to avoid connecting to DB on every page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I code a simple php/mysql web page, that there is *page1.php*, *page2.php* and so on. Because I make use of the database on every page (or at least the 90% of them) I place on the top of them the standard

```
mysql_connect("localhost"," "," ");
mysql_select_db(" ");
.
.
mysql_close();
```

with my queries.

My question is do I really need to connect to the database on each page or is there any way to avoid this and still stay connected? Some of the pages are linked to the others and I can make use of SESSIONS to post some variables, but my question goes to something more globalized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`mysql_pconnect`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php) for a persistent connection, although its not going to help you that much and it can be a big pain to do properly. Its almost just better to connect on every page, especially if the database server is running on the same machine as the php server.

Comment: I feel hesitant to recommend this to someone who wouldn't understand the implications of this.

Comment: You still need to explicitly call mysql_connect ANYWAYS, even with persistent connections. There's still a script->connection pool link that has to be established. persistent connections just keep PHP module->mysql links alive.

Comment: Thank you for this, I guess I have to stay with `include()` due to the complex of this as you said.

Comment: Do NOT use persistent connections unless you really understand how they work. People often use these, because it 'seems' like a good idea, and end up with MySQL server starved of connection slots.

Comment: Hence the "although its not going to help you that much and it can be a big pain to do properly" :P

Comment: +1 for "it won't help you that much". It seems a lot of overhead, but MySQL is highly optimized for this. Many high traffic websites use this method. The queries you're gonna execute consume a lot more resources and time than establishing the connection itself. Persistent connections are hell.

Answer (score 8):

The web works in a disconnected state by nature.  Meaning that you have no idea if the client is going to come back for a second request or not.

Regardless you absolutely want to connect/disconnect from the database on every single page.  This is the only way to ensure you aren't leaking connections and the site can stay responsive.

Most systems have built in ways to handle connection pooling which makes the act of requesting a new connection very very fast and therefore something you don't have to worry about.

Comment: So I guess, having an `include()` is the best solution for me.

Comment: @Nikolai: Yes.  That is one of the most common ways of performing database access within PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
mysql_pconnect()
```

From PHP.net

"acts very much like mysql_connect() with two major differences.

First, when connecting, the function would first try to find a (persistent) link that's already open with the same host, username and password. If one is found, an identifier for it will be returned instead of opening a new connection.

Second, the connection to the SQL server will not be closed when the execution of the script ends. Instead, the link will remain open for future use (mysql_close() will not close links established by mysql_pconnect())."

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking.

Comment: didnt read it properly but a downvote for this seems like a overkill, coulda just commented and i wud ve corrected it

Comment: Although I didn't downvote, it's purpose is for the community to simply say whether or not the post was helpful; which the original answer wasn't.  Consider it as a lesson to take the time to understand a given question before firing off a response.  Also, I just upvoted the current answer as it's a good one.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make it so that you don't have to hard code it into the top of every file write the connection code in a file then use `require /path/to/file/name.php` and it will establish it everytime **Note:** it might be include and not require.

Comment: @Chris Lively thanks I have done that on previous projects because I hate hard coding the SQL connections every time and it makes it easier to maintain.