# Make multiple ajax calls without killing PHP connection to mySQL server?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'll be making multiple ajax calls (maybe 5 in a second and then 0 for 10-100 seconds and then maybe 10 in a second or something like that) in brief intervals.

Is there any way I can avoid starting a new mySQL db connection each time so I don't kill my server?

I'll be using jQuery to make a $.post call 5 times to a php page that might look like this:

```
<?php

db_connection_method();

$variable = $_POST['data'];

mysql_query();

?>
```

Comment: and what have you tried? Also i still dont get it from a single session why are you creating multiple connection(if this is what you meant?)? or if this is some live environment then multiple connections will be made i dont see a point in this. Need more explaination

Comment: That depends from your architecture a lot, let's take a look to Singleton classes

Comment: See updates to original post

Comment: @maxhud: this is a bad Approach unless until its created for some thing like web service.

Comment: I think you can just use Singleton design pattern or you can put your pdo object in $_SESSION and in your script you just have to est if `isset($_SESSION['PDO'])` then use it otherwise make a new connection and set the `$_SESSION['PDO']`

Comment: singleton wil not work. apache wil release connection resources after one request ends.

Comment: @noobie-php what else would I be using jquery, php, and mysql together for other than a web service. That is exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: @maxhud: If this is a same application and ajax request have to go within same application then you can Kinda Create a Persistent DB connection. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164976/beginner-question-on-mysql-and-php-to-avoid-connecting-to-db-on-every-page. If your ajax calls are not Asynchronous then what you are doing is perfect for your scope